# Retrieving all records with Lambda StartsWith()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have the following ActionResult and retrieve records that starting with "query" parameter's value. However, when quesry value is empty or null, the methods returns no record while I want to retrieve all of them. So, do I have to use a if clause and create different lambda clauses, or is it possible to check query parameter and retrieve all of the records by using StartsWith?

```
public ActionResult StudentLookup(string query)
{
    var students = repository.Students.Select(m => new StudentViewModel
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Name = m.Name
    })
    .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith(query));
    return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: you can also achieve same using `Where(m=>(m.Name ??"").StartsWith(query));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, two options:

- Conditionally apply the `Where` clause:

  ```
  IQuerable<StudentModel> students = repository.Students.Select(m => new StudentViewModel
  {
      Id = m.Id,
      Name = m.Name
  });
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
  {
       students= students.Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith(query));
  }
  return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  ```
- Put the check in the `Where` clause itself:

  ```
  var students = repository.Students.Select(m => new StudentViewModel
  {
      Id = m.Id,
      Name = m.Name
  })
  .Where(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) || m.Name.StartsWith(query));
  return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  ```

Comment: No `ToList()` or `ToArray()` call on the IQueryable ?

Comment: @Shyju: Uh, no... why would there need to be? I'd expect the `Json` call to only evaluate it once. (Unless this is some limitation of the `Json` call that I'm unaware of...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot, I like the second method much more :) What about the ToList() and ToArray() methods after lambda expressions? Sometimes I think of that but not sure when I use and when not use them? Any explanations please?

Comment: @binary: Well, you'd typically use those to materialize the query eagerly, e.g. to iterate over it more than once, or to pass to something else where you don't know what it will do with the results.

Comment: @binary I'm sure you like the second method much more, but keep in mind that your database will like much more the first one :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for warning. If there are so much performance differences, I shall switch to the first one. Is it?

Comment: @JonSkeet Which method do you suggest to use? Is the first one is better than the second one?

Comment: For instance EF generates quite ugly query in the second case. While the first method always generates the best SQL query.

Comment: @Ivan: it may be ugly, but the question is whether it actually hurts performance. The first form is potentially uglier in source code, although I agree about it generating the best SQL.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed in general. But IMO conditional `Where` should always be preferable, especially when query provider does not perform constant predicate optimizations. There are a lot of performance issues caused by using such filters, especially when they are a lot. Not counting the redundant parameters - note the 2 parameters in the SQL translation `WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')` just to pass the single string.

Comment: @binary: The performance of the first should be at least as good as the performance of the second, and may be better. But we can't tell how much difference there will be, nor whether it's *significant* in your particular app. You can determine that though, and you should do so.